# Vietnamese children's stories with audio and text

Tags: resource-request, online-learning, vietnamese

I'm looking for children's stories (stories with an easy vocabulary) in Vietnamese, with the text and the audio, so that I can listen to the story and follow the words on the text.

An example would be Aesop's fables.

Does someone know where I could find something like that?

Or what could I search for on Google (what can I search in Vietnamese)?

Comment: You might start with this: https://en.vietnamplus.vn/childrens-books-win-hearts-of-young-readers-and-their-parents/230880.vnp